# System.Data.SQLite in-memory database multi-threading

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am creating a System.Data.SQLite in-memory database using connection string as

```
"Data Source=:memory:",
```

and want to access this database among multi-threads.

Now what I do is to clone the `SQLiteConnection` object and pass the copy to worker threads.

But I found that different threads actually get individual instances of in-memory database, not a shared one. How can I share one in-memory database among threads?

Thanks!

Comment: There's probably a correct way to do this, but if you in a pinch, you could *try* using a [memory mapped file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx) -- It's a little known feature, but essentially, .NET lets you create a fake file, which just points at an area of memory; then anything that tries to access that file [including external apps, etc.] will actually just be working against memory instead. -- Though, I don't know how well SQLite likes multiple threads talking to the same file at once, they might step on each others' feet and corrupt the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the SQLite [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html#sharedmemdb) for in-memory databases, I would try a datasource named with URI filename convention `file::memory:?cache=shared` or the like instead of `:memory:` (and note specifically the cache name that all connections are being told to use).  As explained on the page, every instance of a `:memory:` is distinct from one another, exactly as you found.

Note you may also have to first enable shared-cache mode before making the connections to the in-memory database (as specified in the [shared cache documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html) with a call to `sqlite3_enable_shared_cache(int)` for this to work.

Comment: Would you happen to know how I can do the same in H2?